# How should I properly use a vector of unique_ptrs while maintaining polymorphism?

Tags: c++, vector, polymorphism, stdvector, unique-ptr

I'm attempting to create a `vector` of `unique_ptr`s, which will manage a group of objects that all inherit from the same parent object.

So for example:

Class A (Parent) -> Class B (Child of A) -> Class C (Child of B)

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> all_objs_;
```

So I know that in order to add objects to this `vector` I have to create as such:

```
std::unique_ptr<C> tmp_obj(new C());

all_objs_.push_back( std::move(tmp_obj) );
```

This works okay so far. It actually moves all variables in C properly.

However, although I have included copy constructors, copy assignment, move constructors, move assignment functions in each of my 3 classes, they don't *actually* get called when performing std::move.

I tested this by adding `std::cout << "test\n";` to each of the four functions. And also by trying to change some arbitrary variable.

My move assignment/copy functions look like this:

```
A& A::operator=(const A&& other) { std::cout << "test\n";}
A::A::(const A&& other) { std::cout << "test\n";}

B& B::operator=(const B&& other) { std::cout << "test\n";}
B::B(const B&& other) : A(other) { std::cout << "test\n";}

C& C::operator=(const C&& other) { std::cout << "test\n";}
C::C(const C&& other) : B(other) { std::cout << "test\n";}
```

Have also tried creating the move assignment/copy functions as such:

```
A& A::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<A>&& other) {std::cout << "test\n";}
A::A(const std::unique_ptr<A>&& other) {std::cout << "test\n";}
```

So, although my code is technically working, I have no idea how or why. Also when removing the move functions completely, I get errors.

Comment: No, they don't get called because what you are moving is a pointer, not the underlying object. There seems to be no benefit to using move in this case.

Comment: So is this something I can or should change in some way? Essentially I'm not sure if there are any drawbacks to leave as-is. Also, to confirm: if I had decided I wanted to move the actual objects themselves, I believe I would run in to an object slicing problem right?

Comment: Your code seems fine to me. As I said there's no point in using `std::move`. And yes if you copied or moved the objects into a `vector<A>` then you would have object slicing.

Comment: @john, *"There seems to be no benefit to using move"*, how else would you transfer a `unique_ptr` into a `vector`?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I understand what's going on with the code now. Also want to note that the std::move in this line: "all_objs_.push_back( std::move(tmp_obj) );" is still required as its a unique_ptr. Compiler errors when I remove that.

Comment: @r3musn0x OK apologies, move is necessary, I don't use `unique_ptr` much, I was getting confused with the older `auto_ptr` which did a move by default.

Comment: A rule of thumb: if you have a polymorphic class hierarchy, you should **delete** all copy and move constructors 99% of the time. You won't need them (as you have just discovered) and actually using them would probably be an error (result in object slicing). One exception is when you want to implement a virtual clone method. In this case, make the copy ctors protected. To reiterate, [there is no need in a move constructor](https://ideone.com/b6Fe3D).

Comment: Oh, and delete the copy and move assignment operators too.